# Substract row-values from all other row-values in same matrix

Tags: r, matrix, gis, apply, pythagorean

I have a data frame with geographical locations (two columns) and presence/abstinence data (0/1). What I need to find out is, how many of the other locations lie within their vicinity and have the value 1. That number should then be appended in a fourth column.

```
xcoords <- c(4487754, 4488111, 4487598, 4487417, 4487949, 4487802, 4488011, 4487638, 4487455, 4487478, 4487141, 4487550, 4487547, 4488010, 4487271, 4487170)
ycoords <- c(5294654, 5294706, 5295490, 5293859, 5295313, 5294910, 5294668, 5295399, 5294537, 5294408, 5294927, 5294617, 5294727, 5294953, 5294168, 5295142)
yesno <- round(runif(16, 0, 1),0) 
df <- cbind(xcoords, ycoords, yesno)
```

I set the vicinity to 500 meters (the geodata is in a projected coordinate system, so the units correspond), and will do the calculation using Pythagoras' theorem.

```
buffer <- 500
```

What I do know, is how to build nested for-loops. But I don't want my function to look like this:

```
count.in.buffer <- function(df, buffer){
lon <- df$xcoords
lat <- df$ycoords
count <- rep(0, length(lon))
 for(i in 1:length(lon)){        # for every row...
  for(j in 1:length(lon) - 1){   # ... check all other rows
    nolon <- lon[-i]
    nolat <- lat[-i]
    ifelse(sqrt((abs(lon[i] - nolon[j]))^2 + (abs(lat[i] - nolat[j]))^2) < buffer, ifelse(df$yesno == 1, count[i] <- count[i] + 1, count[i] <- count[i] + 0), count[i] <- count[i] + 0)
   }
  }
 result <- cbind(data, count)
 return(result)
}
```

That would take ages to be computed, because my data frame actually has 67000 rows.

Instead I would want something more efficient, but I don't understand how to convert the inner for-loop to a function I could use in an apply-function row-wise on the whole data frame. But I do suspect, that an apply-function would be the way to go, right?

P.S.: I solved the problem already with a proper GIS, by creating buffer polygons around each data point and linking the other data points to every buffer polygon's attribute table, if they lie within that buffer. But I think it should be much quicker to do in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try moving it into an apply statement, and subsetting your data into those that have values.

First, make a new df that only has those with 1s in the yesno (no point calculating distances for those that don't for the summing):

```
df1 <- df[df[ ,'yesno'] == 1,]
```

Then, we compare each row of df, to all of df1 in a vectorised way, and sum the counts (minusing out our initial count so we dont count it twice):

```
apply(df, 1, function(x){
    sum(sqrt((x[1] - df1[ ,1])^2 +
             (x[2] - df1[ ,2])^2) < buffer) - x[3]

})
```

Comment: This was really quick, thank you for the answer. But please change the direction of the bigger/smaller-symbol. The points that I want to count need to be _inside_ the buffer, sorry if I didn't make that clear in the question.